# Frozen fresh figs to make jellies

Tags: freezing

Can I freeze fresh figs and make the jelly later with the frozen figs. I only get a few at the time and need to freeze until I get enough to make jelly.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean fig jam as jelly is clear and made with fruit juice. Figs don't really do that.

Fresh figs have a delicate texture. When I have frozen them they were just ok. They were damaged and were not nearly like fresh.
However, this damage is nothing compared to the damage caused by boiling them into jam.

Your frozen figs will be fine for jam making.

Freeze them fast to minimize damage, and seal them in an airtight container to prevent freezer burn.
I lay mine out on a cookie sheet until they are frozen solid and then pack in freezer bags for short term storage or vacuum bags for longer term.